# How can i call model.fit() for different data set in for loop?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I develop Convolutional Neural Network in python. I create Sequential model and i want to fit this model for different data set. So i call fit model in for loop. But calling with one data set vs calling in for loop give different results. How can i reset model parameters?
My code is below:

```
for tr_ind in range(len(train_set_month_list)):
    test_dataset_month_info = test_set_month_list[tr_ind];
    train_dataset_month_info = train_set_month_list[tr_ind];

    model = Sequential()
    history = fit_model_cnn(model, train_x_df, train_x_df_reshaped, train_y_df, validation_data_x_df_reshaped,
                            validation_data_y_df, timesteps, epoch_size, batch_size);


def fit_model_cnn(model, train_x_df, train_x_df_reshaped, train_y_df, validation_data_x_df_reshaped,
                  validation_data_y_df,
                  timesteps, epoch_size, batch_size):
    model.add(
        Conv1D(filters=filter_size, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation=activation_func, padding='same',
               input_shape=(timesteps, train_x_df.shape[1] / timesteps)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(node_count, activation=activation_func, kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_type, loss='mse')

    # fit model
    history = model.fit(train_x_df_reshaped, train_y_df.values,
                        validation_data=(validation_data_x_df_reshaped, validation_data_y_df), batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epoch_size)
    return history;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should clear your previous model inside loop so you could use this function which is keras.backend.clear_session().From https://keras.io/backend/: 
This will be solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From a very simplistic point of view, the data is fed in sequentially, which suggests that at the very least, it's possible for the data order to have an effect on the output. If the order doesn't matter, randomization certainly won't hurt. If the order does matter, randomization will help to smooth out those random effects so that they don't become systematic bias. In short, randomization is cheap and never hurts, and will often minimize data-ordering effects.

In other words, when you feed your neural network with different datasets, your model can get biased towards the latest dataset it was trained on.

You should always make sure that your are randomly sampling from all datasets you have.

Comment: I just want to evaluate each data set which is given like first data set. I am trying to automatize get result for each data set seperately. How can i reset all model? Thanks